# Windows Media Player not playing MP4 files, even after I try to install Klite codec pack and media.player.codec.pack

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, codec

Windows Media Player not playing MP4 files, even after I try to install Klite codec pack and media.player.codec.pack

I have looked at ["windows media player cannot play the file" mp4](https://superuser.com/questions/739327/windows-media-player-cannot-play-the-file-mp4)  but that person's problem seemed to be related to certificates

When I try to play any MP4 I get the error

[image]

I tried installing

[image]

I don't know how legit "media player codec pack" is , i tried it after not having any luck with Klite. I got media player codec pack from https://www.mediaplayercodecpack.com/

I noticed that at one point (after installing klite codec pack and before restarting, when I tried to play an mp4), windows media player couldn't play an mp4 and said that due to a problem, 3rd party codecs will be  disabled. I can't see an option to enable them or to see whether they are enabled or disabled.

If I get a codec list by going to organise..layout..show menu bar.

[image]

Then help..about..technical support information

```
Audio Codecs
Type    Name    Format  Binary  Version
ACM     Microsoft IMA ADPCM CODEC   0011        
ACM     Microsoft CCITT G.711 A-Law and u-Law CODEC     0007        
ACM     Microsoft GSM 6.10 Audio CODEC  0031        
ACM     Microsoft ADPCM CODEC   0002        
ACM     Fraunhofer IIS MPEG Layer-3 Codec (decode only)     0055        
ACM     DivX ;-) Audio Compressor   0161        
ACM     Microsoft PCM Converter     0001        
DMO     WMAudio Decoder DMO     0160, 0161, 0162, 0163  WMADMOD.DLL     6.1.7601.19091
DMO     WMAPro over S/PDIF DMO  0162    WMADMOD.DLL     6.1.7601.19091
DMO     WMSpeech Decoder DMO    000A, 000B  WMSPDMOD.DLL    6.1.7601.19091
DMO     MP3 Decoder DMO     0055    mp3dmod.dll     6.1.7601.19091
```

and

```
Video Codecs
Type    Name    Format  Binary  Version
ICM     Microsoft RLE   MRLE    msrle32.dll     6.1.7601.17514
ICM     Microsoft Video 1   MSVC    msvidc32.dll    6.1.7601.17514
ICM     Microsoft YUV   UYVY    msyuv.dll   6.1.7601.17514
ICM     Intel IYUV codec    IYUV    iyuv_32.dll     6.1.7601.17514
ICM     Toshiba YUV Codec   Y411    tsbyuv.dll  6.1.7601.17514
ICM     Cinepak Codec by Radius     cvid    iccvid.dll  1.10.0.13
ICM     Xvid MPEG-4 Codec   XVID        
ICM     x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec    X264    x264vfw.dll     44.2851.44825.0
ICM     Lagarith Lossless Codec     LAGS    lagarith.dll    1.3.27.0
DMO     Mpeg4s Decoder DMO  mp4s, MP4S, m4s2, M4S2, MP4V, mp4v, XVID, xvid, DIVX, DX50  mp4sdecd.dll    6.1.7601.19091
DMO     WMV Screen decoder DMO  MSS1, MSS2  wmvsdecd.dll    6.1.7601.19091
DMO     WMVideo Decoder DMO     WMV1, WMV2, WMV3, WMVA, WVC1, WMVP, WVP2    wmvdecod.dll    6.1.7601.19091
DMO     Mpeg43 Decoder DMO  mp43, MP43  mp43decd.dll    6.1.7601.19091
DMO     MS ATC Screen Decoder 1     MSA1    scdec.dll   15.0.4703.1000
DMO     Mpeg4 Decoder DMO   MPG4, mpg4, mp42, MP42  mpg4decd.dll    6.1.7601.19091
```

and

```
MPEG/DVD Filters
Type    Name    Binary  Version
video   ffdshow Video Decoder   ffdshow.ax  1.3.0.0
video   LAV Video Decoder   LAVVideo.ax     0.69.0.0
video   Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder     msmpeg2vdec.dll     12.0.9200.17037
audio   ffdshow Audio Decoder   ffdshow.ax  1.3.0.0
audio   LAV Audio Decoder   LAVAudio.ax     0.69.0.0
audio   Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder     msmpeg2adec.dll     6.1.7601.23285
```

and

```
Plug-ins
Type    Name    Binary  Version
Background  Bluetooth Headset Plugin    BtWmpPlugIn.dll     6.5.1.5300
```

I'm not sure that shows that the MP4 codecs got installed

I just tried installing CCCP codecs

[image]

And restarted.  I have the same video codecs as before installing CCCP codecs.

[image]

But still same error from windows media player

**ADDED**

Now it's playing. I have no idea what caused it to jump into action. I think it was playing some time back 'cos i'd have noticed if it weren't. So, some mystery there.

Comment: One reason I gave up on WMP years ago.

Comment: Like @Moab, I too gave up on WMP years ago.  I would suggest [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/) (best).. or [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) (good).. both come with all codecs built in.  Both are REALLY free (as in free beer).  Good luck.